# Updating a Razor Model from Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Here's the situation:  I have a Razor-generated list of items (that needs to stay Razor-generated):

```
@model MG.ViewModels.Profile.ProfileDetailsViewModel
foreach (var interest in Model.Interests)
    {
        <span class="subject-title">@interest.SubjectName</span>
        <a data-bind='click: function(){viewDescription(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(interest)))}'class="subject-description-button" href="#" title="View Details">details</a> 
    }
```

Users can update the details of each item by clicking a 'Details' link that encodes the Model for the `viewDescription` javascript function:

```
    self.viewDescription = function (data) {
       // pull data into KO observables
       self.selectedInterestDescription(data.Description);
       self.selectedInterestSubject(data.SubjectName);
       self.selectedInterestId(data.InterestId);
       self.triggerModal(true);
    };
```

Within the modal that gets triggered, the user can send an AJAX request to an endpoint that updates the description.  This much is working as I'd expect.

What I'm struggling with is - when the user is done updating, the razor `Model` still has the old data.  So when the user clicks 'details' from the Razor-generated list after updating, the old `@model` data is encoded.  **How can I push the updated data to the `@Model` from javascript?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I push the updated data to the @Model from javascript?

You absolutely cannot modify anything on the server from javascript. All you can do is an AJAX request to the server which will return refreshed data to the client. Remember that once the view is initially rendered there's no longer any notion of `@Model` on the client. So talking about updating something that doesn't exist hardly makes any sense. After your AJAX request succeeds simply update the corresponding portions of your DOM that need to be updated. The controller action that you are hitting with AJAX could return all the necessary information for that.

Comment: In the success callback of your AJAX call you could do the following: `$('a.subject-description-button').attr('data-bind', 'PUT THE NEW VALUE HERE')`.

Comment: Ah!  I was just discovering that so I deleted my comment, your way is better than what I was about to do though.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just adding something to Darin's answer. You shouldn't even use models with the Razor view when using KO. Server side MVC models can still be needed to add web-related stuff to the backend entities. But there is not gain from binding those models to the razor view. Instead expose a Web api function that gives you all the data. Call these from your KO viewmodels to populate them